# The last/largest semi-prime of the form $16^n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Mr. David Norata of south Borneo conjectures that $16^{317}+1$ is the last/largest semi-prime of the form $16^n+1$. But he didn't give any clue why he is so sure about this, he just said that he has a rough proof.

Note that $16^n+1$ can be a semi-prime if and only if $n$ is a prime number, and some values of $n$ for which $16^n+1$ is a semi-prime are $3,5,7,23,37,89,149,173,251,307, 317, \ldots$.

Can you prove or disprove Mr. Norata's conjecture?

Comment: Use LATEX please.

Comment: It's unclear how you might expect a concise treatment of such a question.  You give no actionable reference by which an interested Reader might assess for themselves a work by "Mr David Norata of [S]outh Borneo", by which you presumably mean the Indonesian portion of the island.

Comment: @Rajada, this is the first time for me to post question to this site

Comment: Okay I will try to edit it.

Comment: One may note that $16^n+1$ is divisible by $17$ for all odd $n$. I find the conjecture dubious, however, being given no reason to believe it.

Comment: I'm also really unclear as what you would expect this question to amount to. Do you want someone to prove or disprove someone's suggested conjecture? This is not really what this website is for.

Comment: Googling David Norata pretty much just leads back to this post. Could the original asker by any chance be the mysterious Mr. Norata?

Comment: The claim that $16^n + 1$ can be semiprime only if $n$ is prime is incorrect unless $n$ is assumed odd.  The fifth Fermat number $2^{2^5} + 1 = 16^8 + 1$ has the two prime factors $641$ and $6700417$ (Euler), and other examples are found in the Wikipedia article on [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Factorization_of_Fermat_numbers).

Comment: Why does anyone care who Mr Norata is?  It's just a math question.

Comment: The primality of $~\dfrac{16^{317}+1}{17}~$ can be verified using the [elliptic curve method](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Answer (score 8):

Mr. David Norata's conjecture is false, since $16^{956}+1 = 65537\cdot\text{P1147}.$

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm via numerical testing that $(16^n+1)/17$ is prime for odd $n<2000$ only if $n=3,5,7,23,37,89,149,173,251,307,317$.